# how to select Row in ios sqlite and retrive it in application

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I want my database should response properly

I am using This Query to Call my database

```
sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT _id,Operator,Circle FROM mobile_codes WHERE _id LIKE "%@"",MobileNum.text]UTF8String];
```

and,

```
sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT _id,Operator,Circle FROM mobile_codes WHERE _id = "%@"",MobileNum.text]UTF8String];
```

I used this two methods but still i didnt get any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is code for connection with sqlite database and simple select query Employee is a model class for accessing its data

```
define @property sqlite3 *ContactDB; in header file
sqlite3_open([_databasePath UTF8String], &_ContactDB);
NSString *stmt=@"select * from employee";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.ContactDB, [stmt UTF8String], -1,&statement, NULL);


while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
{
    self.employee=[[Employee alloc]init];
    self.employee.empId=(NSInteger *)sqlite3_column_int(statement,0);
    self.employee.empName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];
    self.employee.empAddress= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)];
    self.employee.empCity= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)];
    self.employee.empSalary= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sqlite3_column_int(statement,4)];
    self.employee.departmentId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", sqlite3_column_int(statement,5)];
    [self.EmployeesDisplayArray addObject:self.employee];
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```